# CakePHP 3: Routing & switch layout/view, landing page / homepage

Tags: cakephp, url-routing, cakephp-3.0

For the purposes of the project, I need to create the "landing page" for unauthorized users and the "homepage" for authorized users.

Landing pages contain login / register form, while the homepage is dynamic page (dashboard).

Both pages share the same base path '/'.

My question is how to make routing in this approach?

example:

```
<?php 
Router::scope('/', function ($routes) {
    /**
     * Here, we are connecting '/' (base path) ...
     * LANDING  PAGE
     */
    $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home']);

      // HOME PAGE

    $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'home']);


    $routes->fallbacks('DashedRoute');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Session](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.Network.Session.html) class something like this.

```
$session = Session::create(/* config */);
$user = $session->read('Auth.User');
if ($user['someField']) {
    $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'home']);
} else {
    $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home']);
}
```